# Swagger UI shows default example for query parameters (instead of provided one), after manually clearing, clicking "cancel", and "try it out"

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi

I have an OpenAPI 3 query parameter, defined with `in: query`, `style: form`, `explode: true`, and with an example value (full definition at the end).

I see a strange behavior with the example value: when first loading the UI, the values displayed are the given example value. If I manually delete it from the text area, click Cancel and click "Try it out" again, I get the default "additionalProp1" value, instead my specific example.

Is there anywhere else I should define the example, or any flag to set?

Full parameter definition:

```yaml
- name: urlParameters  
  in: query  
  description: A list of key value pairs parameters.  
  style: form  
  explode: true  
  schema:  
    type: object  
    additionalProperties:  
      type: string  
  example: "\r\n{\r\n  \"exampleParameter1\": \"string\",\r\n  \"exampleParameter2\": \"string\",\r\n  \"exampleParameter3\": \"string\"\r\n}"
```

Comment: Open an issue in the Swagger UI repository at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues

Answer (score 0):

If the example is moved to the scheme object, it works